# Set specific height to a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 flex items: header, content and footer. I want everything to flex BUT the header to be exactly 250px... I added a style `.height-250 {max-height: 250px;}` but it is not working.

```css
/* GRID */
.grid {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  background-color: rgba(100, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgb(100, 255, 225);
  padding: 5px;
}
.col-1-12 {
  flex-basis: 8.3333%;
}
.col-2-12 {
  flex-basis: 16.6666%;
}
.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.full-width {
  flex-grow: 100;
}
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.height-250 {
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper grid flex-column">
  <div class="col col-1-12 height-250">Header</div>
  <div class="grid col full-width col-2-12">Content</div>
  <div class="col col-1-12">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `max-height: 250px` you should use `flex: 0 0 250px` and with `flex-direction: column` it will set height of element to 250px.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  background-color: rgba(100, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgb(100, 255, 225);
  padding: 5px;
}
.col-1-12 {
  flex-basis: 8.3333%;
}
.col-2-12 {
  flex-basis: 16.6666%;
}
.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.full-width {
  flex-grow: 100;
}
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.height-250 {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper grid flex-column">
  <div class="col col-1-12 height-250">Header</div>
  <div class="grid col full-width col-2-12">Content</div>
  <div class="col col-1-12">Footer</div>
  </div
```